# Click on a div, take a text and copy paste it in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin in my website and I want to customize a feature that it doesn't provide me.

```
<div id="4_15:00" class="DOPBSPCalendar-hour dopbsp-available">
   <div class="dopbsp-bind-top">
      <div class="dopbsp-hour">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="dopbsp-bind-middle dopbsp-group0">
      <div class="dopbsp-hour">15:00</div>
      <div class="dopbsp-available">1 available</div>
   </div>
   <div class="dopbsp-bind-bottom">
      <div class="dopbsp-hour">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="4_16:30" class="DOPBSPCalendar-hour dopbsp-available dopbsp-selected">
   <div class="dopbsp-bind-top">
      <div class="dopbsp-hour">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="dopbsp-bind-middle dopbsp-group0">
      <div class="dopbsp-hour">16:30</div>
      <div class="dopbsp-available">1 available</div>
   </div>
   <div class="dopbsp-bind-bottom">
      <div class="dopbsp-hour">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the part of the table I want to show the selected time under the date:

```
<table class="dopbsp-cart">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="dopbsp-label">Check in</td>
         <td class="dopbsp-value">19 February 2015</td>
      </tr>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery('.DOPBSPCalendar-hour.dopbsp-available').click(function (e) {
       t = jQuery('.dopbsp-selected .dopbsp-hour').text();
       table = jQuery('table.dopbsp-cart .dopbsp-value');
       table.first().append("<br>"+t)
     });
   });
</script>
```

When a user select a specific time, it automatically adds the class: `dopbsp-selected`. So, I want to take the selected time and add it below the date. However, I don't have any error on the console and I cannot find the reason that doesn't work.

Comment: Which element receives the class `dopbsp-selected`?

Comment: The div that you click. It is on the code. On the second option

Comment: Your code seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/uxy6zxfc/

Comment: Then the problem might be on the plugin or on Wordpress. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong:

```
 jQuery('.DOPBSPCalendar-hour .dopbsp-available').click(function (e) {
                             ^---
```

The space means you want nested elements, the first having `.DOBetc...`, and then a child element with `.dobspetc...`. Try

```
 jQuery('.DOPBSPCalendar-hour.dopbsp-available').click(function (e) {
                             ^--- no space
```

which indicates "any one element with these two classes applied".

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make it work even with that. And still I don't have an error. Sometimes, it looks like it appears for a milisecond and just disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you are using is wrong.

```
.DOPBSPCalendar-hour .dopbsp-available
```

The `space` show that `.dopbsp-available` is nested to `.DOPBSPCalendar-hour`

But what you want is `.DOPBSPCalendar-hour.dopbsp-available`

which means a `element` has both the `classes`